# Tikz-Calendar: How to work with an array of dates?

Tags: tikz-calendar

I want do define a set with dates chemistryclasses={2021-05-25,2021-06-01,2021-06-08,2021-06-15,2021-06-22,2021-06-29,2021-07-06,2021-07-13}
and then I want the code to paint the corresponding dates in tikz-calendar.
In the MWE below I could do that. However, I would like to automatize the routine. It is tedious to write all those `if (equals=2021-05-25)`. At the moment I use Python to write the .tex file. It reads a CSV file with the dates and the generate the .tex file. But I was thinking about an all-LaTeX solution.
I tried something like

```
\foreach \x in {2021-05-25,2021-06-01,2021-06-08,2021-06-15,2021-06-22,2021-06-29,2021-07-06,2021-07-13} {%
  if (equals=\x) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
}
```

but it didn't work. So how can I automatize these things inside LaTeX? A good workflow would be:

1)Write the dates in a file

2)LaTeX reads the dates and save to a variable

3)LaTeX generates the calendar.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,calendar,shapes.geometric}


% =============
% = TColorBox =
% =============
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{left=4mm,sharpish corners,colback=white}


% ============
% = Calendar =
% ============
\newcommand{\calrow}[1]{
\node[anchor=base,xshift=0.5ex](mon){M}; % Shift first weekday
\node[base right=0.1em of mon](tue){T}; 
\node[base right=0.0em of tue](wed){W};
\node[base right=0.0em of wed](thu){T}; 
\node[base right=0.1em of thu](fri){F};
\node[base right=0.2em of fri](sat){S}; 
\node[base right=0.2em of sat](sun){S};
\node[black,above=0.1em of thu]{\textbf{#1}};}
\newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{%
    \calendar (month-#1)[dates=2021-#1-01 to 2021-#1-last,
    every day/.style={anchor=base}, % Center days
    day text={\%d=},rounded corners=0,
    anchor=base,text height=1ex,text depth=-0.5ex] % Make node placement easier
    if(Sunday) [red] 
    \teachingdays;
}
\newcommand{\teachingdays}{
if (equals=2021-05-11) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-05-18) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-05-25) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-06-01) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-06-08) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-06-15) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-06-22) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-06-29) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-07-06) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-07-13) {\node [fill=yellow,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};}
if (equals=2021-05-11) [blue]
if (equals=2021-05-18) [blue]
if (equals=2021-05-25) [blue]
if (equals=2021-06-01) [blue]
if (equals=2021-06-08) [blue]
if (equals=2021-06-15) [blue]
if (equals=2021-06-22) [blue]
if (equals=2021-06-29) [blue]
if (equals=2021-07-06) [blue]
if (equals=2021-07-13) [blue]
}
\newcommand{\generatehyperlinks}{
\node [hyperlink node=data01,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-05-2021-05-11) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data02,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-05-2021-05-18) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data03,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-05-2021-05-25) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data04,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-06-2021-06-01) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data05,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-06-2021-06-08) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data06,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-06-2021-06-15) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data07,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-06-2021-06-22) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data08,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-06-2021-06-29) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data09,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-07-2021-07-06) {};
\node [hyperlink node=data10,draw=none,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] at (month-07-2021-07-13) {};
}
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let     \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
                \n1={\x2-\x1},
                \n2={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}
                    %xelatex needs \XeTeXLinkBox, won't create a link unless it
                    %finds text --- rules don't work without \XeTeXLinkBox.
                    %Still builds correctly with pdflatex and lualatex
        }
    }
}
\linespread{1.3}


\begin{document}

% ============
% = Calendar =
% ============


\begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}]
    \matrix[%
            row 1/.style={black,node distance=.3ex},%
            row 3/.style={black,node distance=.3ex},
            column sep=1ex,draw=none]{%
            % first row: week day and month
            \calrow{May} & \calrow{June} & \calrow{July} \\
            % second row: calendar
            \calperiod{05} & \calperiod{06} & \calperiod{07} \\
            };
            \generatehyperlinks
\end{tikzpicture}


\newpage
\begin{itemize}
    \item \hypertarget{data01}{01}
    \item \hypertarget{data02}{02}
    \item \hypertarget{data03}{03}
    \item \hypertarget{data04}{04}
    \item \hypertarget{data05}{05}
    \item \hypertarget{data06}{06}
    \item \hypertarget{data07}{07}
    \item \hypertarget{data08}{08}
    \item \hypertarget{data09}{09}
    \item \hypertarget{data10}{10}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is tedious to write all those `if (equals=2021-05-25)`.

Then don't. Take a look at the `/pgf/calendar/equals-strip` key that takes an argment as `#1/#2` and forwards `#1` to `equals`. The second part after `/` is only used to place the `\item`s later.

We can use the list inside `\teachingdays` once expanded and fed as a list to `equals-strip`:

```
if (equals-strip/.list/.expand once=\teachingdays) [teaching day]
```

The `\teachingdays` macro can then simply be:

```
\newcommand*\teachingdays{%
  2021-05-11/Intro,
  2021-05-18/Basics I,
  2021-05-25/Basics II,
  …
}
```

This should make it much easier to use the `calendar` libraries by TikZ/PGF.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,calendar}

%%% Shorthand w- for Weekday
\expandafter\def\csname pgfcalendar@shorthand@w-\endcsname{\ifcase\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday M\or T\or W \or T\or F\else S\fi}

%%% equal key that strips /<text>
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{equals-strip/.style args={#1/#2}{equals={#1}}}

%%% A simple parser for <year>-<month>-<day> so we can use shorthands outside of a calendar
\def\pgfcalendarsimpleparse#1-#2-#3\relax{%
  \def\pgfcalendarcurrentyear{#1}%
  \def\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth{#2}%
  \def\pgfcalendarcurrentday{#3}}

%%% hyperling node
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=@hyper,
        append after command={
            let \p1 = (@hyper.north west),
                \p2 = (@hyper.south east),
                \n1 = {\x2-\x1}, \n2 = {\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, anchor=center, at=(@hyper)] {\hyperlink{ref-#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}}}}

\newcommand*{\calrow}[1]{\node[draw,black, minimum width=7*\csname tikz@lib@cal@xshift\endcsname]{\textbf{#1}};}

\newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{%
    \calendar [
      dates=2021-#1-01 to 2021-#1-last,
      day text={\%d=},
      %
      % we name every weekday node (even though we only need the Thursday)
      weekday node/.style={
        black, name=weekday-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday},
      %
      % teaching day, include hyperlink node based on the date
      teaching day/.style={
        days={text=blue, fill=yellow, hyperlink node=\pgfcalendarcurrentyear-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentday}}]
      %
      % standard stuff
      %
      if (Saturday) [red!50!black]
      if (Sunday)   [red]
      %
      % the first day of the month is in the upmost row,
      % let's place the weekday above it and align it properly
      % the name @firstweekday can be referenced later
      %
      if (day of month=1) [days={append after command={
        node [anchor=base east, at={(\tikzlastnode.base east)}, alias=@firstweekday,
          yshift=\csname tikz@lib@cal@yshift\endcsname, weekday node/.try] {\%w-}}}]
      %
      % for all other days 2 to 7 we place the weekday text similar but we use the
      % the first placed weekday text to make sure we align it at the same height
      %
      if (day of month=2, day of month=3, day of month=4, day of month=5, day of month=6, day of month=7) [days={append after command={
        node [anchor=base east, at={(@firstweekday.base east-|\tikzlastnode.base east)}, weekday node/.try] {\%w-}}}]
      %
      % and go
      %
      if (equals-strip/.list/.expand once=\teachingdays) [teaching day]
      ;
}
\newcommand*\teachingdays{%
  2021-05-11/Intro,
  2021-05-18/Basics I,
  2021-05-25/Basics II,
  2021-06-01/And,
  2021-06-08/Much,
  2021-06-15/More,
  2021-06-22/Stuff,
  2021-06-29/To Do,
  2021-07-06/In,
  2021-07-13/Class}

\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}]
    \matrix[column sep=1.5ex]{%
       \calperiod{05} & \calperiod{06} & \calperiod{07} \\
    };
    \foreach \mon/\t in {05/May, 06/Jun, 07/Jul}
      \node[anchor=south, yshift=2ex, at=(weekday-\mon-3)] {\textbf{\t}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagebreak
\setlength{\labelwidth}{4em}
\begin{itemize}
    \foreach \target/\name[/utils/exec=\let\%\pgfcalendarshorthand] in \teachingdays {
      \expandafter\pgfcalendarsimpleparse\target\relax
      \item[\%m. \%d= \%y-] \hypertarget{ref-\target}{\name}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: three months side by side]
[image: list of teachings]