# Mark all dates contained in a list in Tikz calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calendar

I am trying to mark (in green text color) the dates contained in a list (`\myDates`) using an if statement within a tikz calendar. I can't figure out how to iterate through the list so all dates contained inside it get marked. The way I'm currently doing it only marks the first date in `\myDates`. Here's a MWE. I'm compiling with XeLaTeX. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\def\year{2024}
\def\month{02}
\newcommand*\myDates{%
    2024-02-15,%
    2024-02-19,%
    2024-03-17,%
    2024-04-13
}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{CMU Bright}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,calendar}

\begin{document}

% MINI CALENDAR
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar
    [
    dates=\year-\month-01 to \year-04-last,
    week list,
    month label above centered,
    month text=\textcolor{black}{\bfseries\%mt \%y-},
    day xshift = 8mm
    ]
    if (Sunday) [red!50]
    if (equals=\myDates) [green]
    ;    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also check  this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356224/tikz-calendar-loop-through-array-of-dates-to-mark-vacations

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do is use the nodes defined by the calendar by iterating through dates and using `(mycal-\date)` to draw circle.

```latex
    % MINI CALENDAR
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \calendar (mycal)
        [
            dates=\year-\month-01 to \year-04-last,
            week list,
            month label above centered,
            month text=\textcolor{black}{\bfseries\%mt \%y-},
            day xshift = 8mm
        ]
        if (Sunday) [red!50]
%       if (equals={2024-04-16,2024-02-15}) [green] 
        ;   
        \foreach \date in {2024-04-13,2024-02-15, 2024-02-15, 2024-03-17}{
            \draw [green,fill,opacity=0.2] (mycal-\date) circle[radius=7pt];    
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, if I replace the list in `\foreach` with `\myDates` I get an error (Package pgf Error: No shape named `mycal-2024/02/15' is known.).

Comment: I got the same. I didn't have time to investigate that part yet. Maybe it is worth another question because it doesn't seem to be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

something like the following -- my detailed answer with the syntax and citation to the original is here -- [How highlight date or week in TikZ Calendar with background color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709665/how-highlight-date-or-week-in-tikz-calendar-with-background-color/709680?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.6034#709680)

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,calendar}

%%% Shorthand w- for Weekday
\expandafter\def\csname pgfcalendar@shorthand@w-\endcsname{\ifcase\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday M\or T\or W \or T\or F\else S\fi}

%%% equal key that strips /<text>
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{equals-strip/.style args={#1/#2}{equals={#1}}}

%%% A simple parser for <year>-<month>-<day> so we can use shorthands outside of a calendar
\def\pgfcalendarsimpleparse#1-#2-#3\relax{%
    \def\pgfcalendarcurrentyear{#1}%
    \def\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth{#2}%
    \def\pgfcalendarcurrentday{#3}}

%%% hyperling node
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=@hyper,
        append after command={
            let \p1 = (@hyper.north west),
            \p2 = (@hyper.south east),
            \n1 = {\x2-\x1}, \n2 = {\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, anchor=center, at=(@hyper)] {\hyperlink{ref-#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}}}}

\newcommand*{\calrow}[1]{\node[draw,black, minimum width=7*\csname tikz@lib@cal@xshift\endcsname]{\textbf{#1}};}

\newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{%
    \calendar [
    dates=2024-#1-01 to 2024-#1-last,
    day text={\%d=},
    %
    % we name every weekday node (even though we only need the Thursday)
    weekday node/.style={
        black, name=weekday-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday},
    %
    % teaching day, include hyperlink node based on the date
    teaching day/.style={
        days={text=blue, fill=green, hyperlink node=\pgfcalendarcurrentyear-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentday}}]
    %
    % standard stuff
    %
    if (Saturday) [blue!50]
    if (Sunday)   [red]
    %
    % the first day of the month is in the upmost row,
    % let's place the weekday above it and align it properly
    % the name @firstweekday can be referenced later
    %
    if (day of month=1) [days={append after command={
            node [anchor=base east, at={(\tikzlastnode.base east)}, alias=@firstweekday,
            yshift=\csname tikz@lib@cal@yshift\endcsname, weekday node/.try] {\%w-}}}]
    %
    % for all other days 2 to 7 we place the weekday text similar but we use the
    % the first placed weekday text to make sure we align it at the same height
    %
    if (day of month=2, day of month=3, day of month=4, day of month=5, day of month=6, day of month=7) [days={append after command={
            node [anchor=base east, at={(@firstweekday.base east-|\tikzlastnode.base east)}, weekday node/.try] {\%w-}}}]
    %
    % and go
    %
    if (equals-strip/.list/.expand once=\myDates) [teaching day]
    ;
}
\newcommand*\myDates{%
    2024-04-8/Intro,
    2024-04-9/Basics I,
    2024-04-10/Basics II,
    2024-04-11/And}

\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}\noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}],
        \matrix[column sep=1.5ex]{%
            \calperiod{04} &  &  \\
        };
        \foreach \mon/\t in {04/April}
        \node[anchor=south, yshift=2ex, at=(weekday-\mon-3)] {\textbf{\t}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    %   \pagebreak
    %   \setlength{\labelwidth}{4em}
    %   \begin{itemize}
        %       \foreach \target/\name[/utils/exec=\let\%\pgfcalendarshorthand] in \myDates{
            %           \expandafter\pgfcalendarsimpleparse\target\relax
            %           \item[\%m. \%d= \%y-] \hypertarget{ref-\target}{\name}}
        %   \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```